# Github pages react app didn`t get response

Tags: reactjs, github, axios, github-pages

I have react app what I already deployed to the GitHub Pages.

But now I have a problem: what I am requesting auth status to server and didn`t get any response. What is the problem?

I have this error in console about my requests

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Comment: You have to give us more information than that. What error are you getting, what is your exact request, etc? What have you tried so far to solve this and what resources have you looked at?

Comment: I have this error in console about my requests

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub pages supports CORS [since 2015](https://twitter.com/invisiblecomma/status/575219895308324864), so you can follow "[Fix CORS Error| React Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxyp_LkKDdk)" which points to:

- "[Run Chrome browser without CORS](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/)" (not recommended, just for testing)
- [axios/axios issue 853](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/853)

That last issue mentions:

> cURL does not enforce CORS rules. Those rules are enforced by browsers for security purposes.
>
> When you mention that you added the relevant header, I assume you mean you added those headers to the request.
>   **Actually, the header is expected in the response headers from the server, indicating that the resource is allowed to be accessed by other websites directly**.
>
> FYI, CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing. Since your API does not support it, you have two options -
>
> - Use a proxy server on the same domain as your webpage to access 4chan's API or,
> - Use a proxy server on any other domain, but modify the response to include the necessary headers.